# ContentControl DataTemplate binding to primitive types

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate, contentcontrol

I have a viewmodel with a propety that can be a primitive type:

```
class VM : VMBase // implements INotifyProperty
{
    // can be float, int or bool (System.Single, System.Int32, System.Boolean)
    private object _Value;
    public object Value {
        get{return _Value;}
        set{
            if(_Value!=value){
                _Value=value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value)); // notify bindings
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The type of `Value` can be `float`, `int` or `bool`. Now I'd like to display a `TextBox` if `Value`'s type is `float` or `int` and a `CheckBox` if it's a `bool`. In XAML I try this:

```
<Grid> <!-- DataContext is VM -->
   <Grid.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Single}">
         <TextBox Width="64" Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Int32}">
         <TextBox Width="64"/>
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Boolean}">
         <CheckBox Width="64"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </Grid.Resources>
      <ContentControl Content="{Binding Value}" IsTabStop="False"/>
   </Grid>
```

It displays the controls correctly for each type. But I'm unable to use the binding to modify the value of `Value` property by typing a new value in its text box. How should I make a two-way binding? Is there a better method to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've correctly spotted you need to specify a Template for each view of the data, the part that you are missing is that you can then use a [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to choose the correct one

eg

code

```
public class CustomTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate Template1{get;set;}
    public DataTemplate Template2{get;set;}
    public DataTemplate Template3{get;set;}
    public DataTemplate Template4{get;set;}

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if(item is float)
            return Template1;
        else if(item is int)
            return Template1;
        else if(item is string)
            return Template2;
        else if(item is bool)
            return Template3;
        //etc
        else
            return Template4;
    }
}
```

xaml

```
<local:CustomeDataTemplate>
    <local:CustomeDataTemplate.Template1>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding }" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:CustomeDataTemplate.Template1>
    <local:CustomeDataTemplate.Template2>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding }"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:CustomeDataTemplate.Template2>
</local:CustomeDataTemplate>
```

remember to bind the content of the template to the data

Comment: The problem is not the selection of the correct template. That works just fine. I need to be able to modify the data that is bound to the control in each template.

Comment: @rashmatash ah in that case the problem is simpler you haven't bound the control to the data

Comment: I did for the `float` case as you'd see in my code.

Comment: i think your missunderstanding something on the binding, if you just bind to "{Binding}" then you are binding to the datacontext of the current context as the context inside the DataTemplate is to Value (from ContentControl Content="{Binding Value}") then you just need to bind to the Context

Comment: yes, that's also what I tried. But it doesn't do the two-way binding. Only one-way. :(

Comment: I did a variation of your suggestion and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Your welcome, was just working through a real code example for you, but simple rule of thumb is that if a control has a template selector that is the best way to select templates